# Turtles do not stop when condition is set in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have been trying to make a turtle (user) stop when they find a other turtle (bin). For this, the user own waste production that is equal to 0.9. Once they find the bin (bin own bin_holding_capacity) they lose the 0.9.
I want one of them to stop once they find the first bin around them.

The part of the code that I have written is as it follows:

```
to throw-waste     
ask one-of users [       
if any? bins with [distance myself <= 1] [ set wasteproduction ( - 0.9)]     
]    
ask one-of users [     
  if wasteproduction = ( - 0.9)  [ ask users [wait 60] ] ;[stop]       
]    
end

to receive-waste
 ask bins [
 if any? users with [distance myself <= 1]  [set bins_holding_capacity bins_holding_capacity + 0.9 ]
  if bins_holding_capacity  >= 38 [stop]
  if any? collectors with [distance myself <= 1] [set bins_holding_capacity bins_holding_capacity - 25 ]
 ]
end
```

If someone could help me with this, I would appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: I think we'd need to see your  `move` procedure code but perhaps a simple flag would suffice, don't only ask them to `stop` but also turn a flag on, you want to valide this flag state in the `move` procedure.